# Having trouble passing a value from one input to another with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a little noob project and making a simple "to-do list" and I'm stuck on something that seems so simple! I'm trying to pass the main  up top from #myInput and pass it to the next  down and so on. Right now, if you enter something then click add, it creates a blank new line at first for some reason then if you type something else and click add, what you typed before shows up on the next line. It will keep doing that for as long as you type something different in the input, but if you keep hitting add a couple times with the same thing in the input, nothing shows up. Then change the input again to something different and click add and all that will show up lol, but still no current line outputs from what you typed...going nuts. Any suggestions on the proper way to do this? I left a JSfiddle link to see exactly what is happening down below.

```
<div>
  <form id="addThings" type="text">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="add to your to-do list" size="50" maxlength="40" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="add">
  </form>
</div>
```

Also, when you click the button and it creates a new line down below it shifts everything around a bit..ideas on what needs to be changed in the css? Trying to get it a little smoother. Thanks!

```
$(function() {
  var i = 2;
  $('#addButton').click(function(e) {
    var input = $('#myInput').val();
    console.log(input);
    var id = "newLine" + i;
    var line = '<input type=\"text\" id=\"' + id + '\" size=\"50\" disabled><input type=\"checkbox\" >';    
    $('form').append(line);
    var newId = "#" + id;
    $('#myInput').change(function() {
      $(newId).val(input);
    });
    i += 1;
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97t9ztd6/8/)

Comment: Search for javascript closures.

Comment: Why not somthing as easy as this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YuriJF/97t9ztd6/12/)

Comment: thanks for the info guys! Definitely read up on closures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Providing a value to the input field before you append it works well.In your case there is an issue with javascript closure. To solve it just define the input variable outside of the `click` function

```
$(function() {
  var i = 2;
  $('#addButton').click(function(e) {
    var input = $('#myInput').val();
    console.log(input);
    var id = "newLine" + i;
    var line = '<input type=\"text\" id=\"' + id + '\" value=\"'+input+'\" size=\"50\" disabled><input type=\"checkbox\" >';
    console.log(line);
    $('form').append(line);

    i += 1;
  });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/97t9ztd6/10/)**

Comment: Try explaining _why_ and _how_ your proposed solution fixes OP's code instead of just providing a code snippet without any commentary.

Comment: @kb. thanks for the tip. I will keep that in my from now

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri wow, can't believe I was stuck on something so simple...there I go overthinking things! Did not even think about the value attr. Don't know what would smooth out that shifting in the css would ya?

Comment: @BruceO. Happy to Help! :) Regarding the CSS I will try to see.

Comment: I got it..finally figured it out...I just put everything into two seperate div's to manipulate it :) https://jsfiddle.net/j4cp3kuc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the input value to the value attribute of your new input when you create the new line:

```js
$(function() {
  var i = 2;
  $('#addButton').click(function(e) {
    var input = $('#myInput').val();
    var id = "newLine" + i;
    var line = '<input type=\"text\" id=\"' + id + '\" size=\"50\" value="' + input + '" disabled><input type=\"checkbox\">';
    $('form').append(line);
    var newId = "#" + id;
    /*$('#myInput').change(function() {
      $(newId).val(input);
    });*/
    i += 1;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

div {
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

input {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  float: bottom;
}

input[type=text] {
  border-left: white;
  border-right: white;
  border-top: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  i height: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
}

input[type=button] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px border: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 15px auto;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>
    <form id="addThings" type="text">
      <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="add to your to-do list" size="50" maxlength="40" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
      <input type="button" id="addButton" value="add">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a closure/scope issue. Your variable `input` is inside the `click` function. Therefore it is not going to be in the scope of the `change` function.

Move the declaration of `input`outside of the `click` function.

**Create a wrapper function.**

That way all the variables needed are in the scope of `addButtonScopeFunc` and there only.

Those variables aren't needed in the global scope `window.` nor in the scope of the `'#addButton'` event function.

```
$(function() {
  var addButtonScopeFunc = function (input, inputValChangeEl) {
      var i = 2,
          id = "newLine" + i,
          newId = "#" + id,
          line = '<input type=\"text\" id=\"' + id + '\" size=\"50\" disabled><input type=\"checkbox\" >';
      console.log(input);
      console.log(line);
      $('form').append(line);
      $(inputValChangeEl).change(function() {
          $(newId).val(input);
      });
      i += 1;
    };
    $('#addButton').click(function(e) {
        addButtonScopeFunc($('#myInput').val(), '#myInput'); 
    });
});
```

---

To give an other example, just for showing up things.

You could "*outscope*" the `$(inputValChangeEl).change(...)` event function outside of `addButtonScopeFunc` in its own wrapper function handling over the `input` value as parameter.

```
$(function() {
  var addButtonScopeFunc = function (input, inputValChangeEl) {
      /* ... */
      $('form').append(line);
      changeInputVal(inputValChangeEl, newId, input); 
      i += 1;
  },
  changeInputVal = function (el, id, input) {
      $(el).change(function() {
          $(id).val(input);
      });
  };
  $('#addButton').click(function(e) {
      addButtonScopeFunc($('#myInput').val(), '#myInput'); 
  });
});
```

Further reading: [Javascript Scopes well explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: This will bind change event every time addButton is clicked

Comment: @Yuri Edited answer